# Build custom jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok anybody familiar with building your own custom jQuery selection from DOM nodes or jQuery objects?

For examle:

```
var li = jQuery('li.someclass');
var myDiv = jQuery('#mydiv');
```

So I would like to combine those two into one `jQuery(object)` .

It would be nice if it can be done 
dynamically using nodes cached in variables like the provided example.
BR and 10x for your kind help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the results with [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
var combined = li.add(myDiv);
```

---

*Note that `.add()` doesn't really do what it claims. It doesn't add anything to the `li` jQuery object. It creates a new jQuery object with the merged results.*

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following in this case:

```
var obj = jQuery('#mydiv, li.someclass');
```

Then any method performed on `obj` would apply to both `#mydiv` and `li.someclass`. For example, to give a red border to both elements:

```
obj.css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Comment: Furthermore, jQuery uses the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selection engine, which supports any CSS3-style selection.